# Check if an array is sorted or not using recursion

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

Here is my code:

```
def isSorted(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return True
    elif arr[n-2] > arr[n-1]:
        return False
    return isSorted(arr[0:n-1])

arr = [1,9,9,4,5]    
isSorted(arr)    
if isSorted:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer is always `yes`, even if the array is unsorted. Can anybody please explain what mistake am I making?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use recursion for this? It's going to be remarkably inefficient for this trivial use-case

Comment: If you feel that none of the answers have addressed your question, please edit the question to clarify whatever issues your respondents have missed, noting that changing the question by “moving the goalposts” is frowned upon. Alternatively, If one or more answers have been helpful please read [“What should I do when someone answers my question?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) from the help section of the site (which you can browse by clicking on the question mark in the upper right corner of the window).

Answer (score 1):

Your code was fine with the exception of the error noted in the comments:  you were ignoring the return value of isSorted(arr) by just checking `if isSorted:`.  `isSorted` is a callable (and not None or zero or an empty string, etc.) and thus evaluates to True.

Here's a slight modification to your code, using negative indices to count back from the end of the array.  For example, `-2` is the same as `n-2` when n is the length of the array.

I've also thrown in a little syntactic sugar at the end, using python's ternary operator.

```
def isSorted(arr):

    if len(arr) < 2:
        return True

    elif arr[-2] > arr[-1]:
        return False

    return isSorted(arr[:-1])

arr = [1,9,9,4,5]


print("yes" if isSorted(arr) else  "no")
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach can be implemented like this:

```
def isSorted(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return True
    return False if lst[1] < lst[0] else isSorted(lst[1:])
```

However, it's going to be slow compared with:

```
lst == sorted(lst)
```

...due to the efficient implementation of the *sort()* function

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are non-recursive solutions which will outperform recursive implementations.

Having said that, if you insist on using recursion you should seek approaches that will not give you a stack overflow with larger arrays. Solutions which whittle the size of the problem down one element at a time will cause stack overflow on arrays that are larger than ~1000 elements. To avoid this, use an approach which cuts the problem size in half at each level of the recursion. The following algorithm does this:

```python
def isSorted(ary):
    if len(ary) < 2:
        return True
    mid = len(ary) // 2
    return (ary[mid-1] <= ary[mid]) and isSorted(ary[:mid]) and isSorted(ary[mid:])
```

The logic is:

- Arrays of length less than 2 are trivially considered sorted, so return `True` if this is the case;
- Otherwise, find the mid-range value which will split the array into two sub-arrays which differ in length by no more than one;
- The array is sorted if and only if the last element of the first sub-array is ≤ the first element of the second subarray, and both sub-arrays are sorted.

Since `and` is used, short-circuiting can occur. The recursive stack size is O(log(`len(ary)`).

As Mark pointed out, the reason you always get "yes" is because `isSorted`, without an argument, is a reference to the function and is considered "truthy" in python.

Comment: Could improve it further from O(n log n) to O(n) by passing indexes, but I guess yours is already better than what they're supposed to do :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy Agreed, but I figured I'd avoid the added complexity of writing a public facing front end or adding indices the end-user needs to supply (and likely screw up).

Answer (score -1):

```py
def isSorted(arr):
    # Base case: An empty or single-element array
    #            is always sorted.
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return True

    # For an array to be sorted, the next element must be <=
    # than the previous element.
    elif arr[1] > arr[0]:
        return False

    # Tail recursion for the remaining elements
    return isSorted(arr[1:])

def printIsSorted(arr):
    if isSorted(arr):
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")

printIsSorted([1, 9, 9, 4, 5]) # prints no
printIsSorted([7, 5, 3, 2, 1]) # prints yes
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the parameters to the function in the `if` statement:

```py
if isSorted(arr):
    print("yes")
else
    print("no")
```